# How to determine the ID of the invoking button or open taskpane from inside office-JS

Tags: javascript, office-js, excel-addins

I have an Excel javascript addin that creates multiple buttons on the ribbon, and each button invokes a taskpane. The javascript code that these buttons need to execute is the same except for a single line deep in the callstack that determines the server address we send the next request off to when we're populating the taskpane. I'd like to know what the easiest way is to tell which button the user pushed to get to where we are; I'd prefer to avoid sending different javascript to the client for the second button if possible.

In the Addin's manifest, I've set a unique ID for the button and the taskpane - is there any way to access either of these from the javascript? I've found Office.context.ui but it doesn't seem to contain any information about the current UI context.

Comment: Just to clarify; you have two buttons (B1 and B2 for example). Both B1 and B2 open the same URI in the Taskpane?

Comment: I would like them to both open the same, since the code I need to push down is large and would only differ by a single line otherwise. If there's no other way to do this than to have them point to different URLs, I can do that too.

Answer (score 1):

The ID of the button isn't surfaced during the click event. It is however an interesting suggestion. I would suggest you add to the Office [Developers UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

When I've run into similar use cases, we've typically approached it by creating two distinct URIs. Each button simply points to it's own URI. When that URI launches however, it immediately redirects to the primary application page. In order to maintain the execution path, we include a query parameter that tells the main app page where it came from. You could use this same model to pass along which button was pushed in the ribbon.

If you go this route, make sure you initial URI contains it's own Office.initialize implementation. You can use this method to execute the navigation to the main page. Without it you may run into issues as Office assumes each add-in page implements Office.initialize.